# Postgres how to make more than one transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a problem makin more than one insertion into the database, my problem initial it was that i couldn't insert into the table beacause i need the last id of the last record inserted.

if i try to insert more records to the table, it doesn't work, why? that's because is inserted until transaction is commited,so it only will insert one record with the last id inserted.
here is my java code:

```
@Service 
@Transactional
public class ServicioEvaluacionImpl implements ServicioEvaluacion{


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sfGas")
    SessionFactory sf;

    Session session;    

    @Autowired
    EncuestaDaoImpl encuestaDao;

    @Autowired
    ClienteDaoImpl clienteDao;
    @Autowired
    DelegacionDaoImpl delegacionDao;
    @Autowired
    ServicioGenericoCRUD  servicioCRUD;


    public void guardarEvaluacion(String parametros) {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(parametros);

        JSONObject cliente = obj.getJSONObject("cliente");


        Integer lastIdCliente = new Integer(0);

        String nombre = cliente.getString("nombre");
        String apellidos = cliente.getString("apellidos");
        String sexo = cliente.getString("sexo");
        String email = cliente.getString("email");
        String area = cliente.getString("area");
        String puesto = cliente.getString("puesto");
        int delegacion = cliente.getInt("delegacion");

        Delegacion delegacionObj = delegacionDao.getDelegacion(delegacion);

        Cliente clienteObj = new Cliente();
        clienteObj.setNombre(nombre);
        clienteObj.setApellidos(apellidos);
        clienteObj.setEmail(email);
        clienteObj.setSexo(sexo);
        clienteObj.setPuesto(puesto);
        clienteObj.setArea(area);
        clienteObj.setDelegacion(delegacionObj);
        //clienteDao.setCliente(clienteObj);
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try{
            Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();

             //obtiene ultimo id insertado
            List<Object> qTemp = servicioCRUD.consultaSQL("Select max(id_cliente) from cliente;");

            for(Object registro : qTemp){

                lastIdCliente = Integer.parseInt(registro.toString());
            }

            int ultimoID = lastIdCliente.intValue()+1;

            clienteObj.setIdCliente(ultimoID);
            servicioCRUD.create(clienteObj);        


        JSONArray evaluaciones = obj.getJSONArray("evaluaciones");
        JSONArray idPregunta = obj.getJSONArray("idPregunta");
        JSONArray comentarios = obj.getJSONArray("comentarios");
        String sugerencias = obj.getString("sugerencias");

        Respuestas respuesta = new Respuestas();
        Comentarios comentario = new Comentarios();
        Sugerencias sugerencia = new Sugerencias();
    respuesta.setCliente(clienteObj);
    comentario.setCliente(clienteObj);
    sugerencia.setCliente(clienteObj);

    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()); 
    sugerencia.setFecha(sqlDate);
    sugerencia.setSugerencia(sugerencias);

        for (int i = 0; i < evaluaciones.length(); i++) {

              transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            Encuesta pregunta = encuestaDao.getEncuesta(idPregunta.getInt(i));

            respuesta.setEncuesta(pregunta);


            int respuestaID=0;

            //obtiene ultimo id de respuesta
             qTemp = servicioCRUD.consultaSQL("SELECT max(id_respuesta) FROM respuestas");

                for(Object registro : qTemp){

                Integer lastIdPregunta = Integer.parseInt(registro.toString());
                 respuestaID = lastIdPregunta.intValue()+1;
                 System.out.println("loop::"+i+"   -ult id resp: "+ respuestaID);
                }

                respuesta.setCalificacion((short) evaluaciones.getInt(i));
                respuesta.setIdRespuesta(respuestaID);


                //insercion respuestas
                respuesta.setFecha(sqlDate);
                servicioCRUD.create(respuesta);

                //si no hay comentarios no insertar
            if(!comentarios.getString(i).equals("")){

                  int commentID = 0;
                 qTemp = servicioCRUD.consultaSQL("SELECT max(id_comentario) FROM comentarios");

                    for(Object registro : qTemp){

                    Integer lastIdComent = Integer.parseInt(registro.toString());
                    commentID = lastIdComent.intValue()+1;
                    }

                    comentario.setEncuesta(pregunta);
                    comentario.setIdComentario(commentID);
                    comentario.setComentario(comentarios.getString(i));
                    comentario.setFecha(sqlDate);
                    servicioCRUD.create(comentario);

            } 

             transaction.commit();

            }
          transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        if(!sugerencias.equals("")){

              int sugerenciaID = 0;
                 qTemp = servicioCRUD.consultaSQL("SELECT max(id_comentario) FROM comentarios");

                    for(Object registro : qTemp){

                    Integer sugerenciaIdComent = Integer.parseInt(registro.toString());
                    sugerenciaID = sugerenciaIdComent.intValue()+1;
                    }
                    sugerencia.setIdSugerencia(sugerenciaID);
                    servicioCRUD.create(sugerencia);


        }

         transaction.commit();



        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
        }finally{

            session.flush();

        }




    }

}
```

i tried to commit at the end of the loop but it gives an error. there is another way to fix the table sequence without the workaround? if not, what i can do? i need to insert those records in a sequence.

**EDIT:**
i fixed the problem with the table sequence, still i can't save those more than one record into the database, there is no stack trace errors this time.

Stack trace:

```
11:03:21,812 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) loop::0   -ult id resp: 5

11:03:22,118 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) loop::1   -ult id resp: 5

11:03:22,195 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

11:03:22,195 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:127)

11:03:22,196 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at com.gas.servicioImpl.ServicioEvaluacionImpl.guardarEvaluacion(ServicioEvaluacionImpl.java:163)

11:03:22,196 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at com.gas.rest.EvaluacionController.setEvaluaciones(EvaluacionController.java:24)

11:03:22,196 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

11:03:22,197 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

11:03:22,197 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

11:03:22,197 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

11:03:22,198 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)

11:03:22,198 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)

11:03:22,198 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)

11:03:22,199 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)

11:03:22,199 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:672)

11:03:22,200 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:82)

11:03:22,200 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)

11:03:22,200 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)

11:03:22,201 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)

11:03:22,201 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)

11:03:22,202 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)

11:03:22,202 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)

11:03:22,202 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

11:03:22,203 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

11:03:22,203 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

11:03:22,203 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:230)

11:03:22,204 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)

11:03:22,204 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)

11:03:22,204 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

11:03:22,205 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

11:03:22,205 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

11:03:22,205 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

11:03:22,206 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

11:03:22,206 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

11:03:22,207 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

11:03:22,207 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

11:03:22,207 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

11:03:22,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

11:03:22,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

11:03:22,208 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

11:03:22,209 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/gasnaturalfenosa].[appServlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Servlet.service() para servlet appServlet lanzó excepción: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gas.servicioImpl.ServicioEvaluacionImpl.guardarEvaluacion(ServicioEvaluacionImpl.java:192) [classes:]
    at com.gas.rest.EvaluacionController.setEvaluaciones(EvaluacionController.java:24) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) [spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:672) [spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:82) [spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919) [spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:230) [spring-orm-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Please add the stacktrace to your Question.

Comment: `select max(id)` is a horrible "workaround". It won't work properly even if you get the obfuscation layer to handle multiple transactions. You should rather fix the reason why you can't use sequences. That's the only safe way to generate ids

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name already fixed, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't your commit. It's a `NullPointerException` line 192.

I don't know which line 192 is, but I bet it's a line outside of your transaction block. When you try to rollback the transaction, you get another Exception from the `Catch - Rollback`.

Look for the Null variable, and you may solve your problem. You may also check if the transaction is open when you try to Rollback. Or add more `try {} catch {}` blocks since your code is very error prone.

Comment: yep, that was part of the problem, also i didn't realise i needed to create a new class for each record